# docker.service not starting under Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: docker

On my notebook running x64 Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon, I tried to install Docker:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
  --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo 
ubuntu-xenial main'

sudo apt update

sudo apt install linux-image-generic linux-image-extra-virtual

sudo apt install docker-engine
```

Only during the last step, the process fails. I guess that it is actually installing the software but my system cannot execute the Docker service:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Di 2018-
02-
27 10:45:35 CET; 17ms ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 9906 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 9906 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 27 10:45:35 silberpfeil systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker 
Application Container Engine.
Feb 27 10:45:35 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered 
failed state.
Feb 27 10:45:35 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
```

"Silberpfeil" is the name of my system. In this error protocol, there is a hint that says that I should look up this error under

- "systemctl status docker.service"
- "journalctl -xe"

The first one returns:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Di 2018-02-27 
10:45:38 CET; 9min ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 10011 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 10011 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker 
Application Container Engine.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered 
failed state.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-
off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application 
Container Engine.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request 
repeated too quickly.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker 
Application Container Engine.
```

The second one says way too much things to post them here. As far as you do not need it for help. Overlooking it, I could see something saying Docker by looking with grep:

```
Feb 27 10:45:37 silberpfeil dockerd[10011]: time="2018-02-
27T10:45:37.123564185+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new 
containerd process, pid: 10033"
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil dockerd[10011]: time="2018-02-
27T10:45:38.129863280+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to rename 
/var/lib/docker/tmp for background deletion: %!s(<nil>). Deleting 
synchronously"
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil dockerd[10011]: time="2018-02-
27T10:45:38.140660647+01:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior 
storage driver aufs failed: driver not supported"
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil dockerd[10011]: Error starting daemon: 
error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process 
exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered 
failed state.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-
off time over, scheduling restart.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down
-- Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request 
repeated too quickly.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
Feb 27 10:45:38 silberpfeil systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered 
failed state.
```

Is anyone able to find something?

Comment: I would guess you don't have the aufs driver. See if you can either install aufs, either switch to overlayfs or overlayfs2. potential informations: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/ . aufs might require a specific aufs-dkms package (it does on Debian). Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I did not overlook the part about the not supported drivers again and found out, that is was really about the AUFS driver respectively the so called graphdriver.

Looking up "docker graphdriver not supported" in a internet search engine gave me the following hint: https://askubuntu.com/questions/870889/cant-start-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-driver-not-supported-error#870890. So all to do, for me, was

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

See the linked answer for more details.